# yesod how to solve this error?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am  just started with Yesod, I am following this tutorial:http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/
I get this error:

```
Handler/Blog.hs:32:17:
Couldn't match type `handler' with `GHandler App App'
  `handler' is a rigid type variable bound by
            the type signature for postBlogR :: handler RepHtml
            at Handler/Blog.hs:29:14
Expected type: handler [Entity Article]
  Actual type: GHandler App App [Entity Article]
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  articles <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc ArticleTitle]
In the expression:
  do { articles <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc ArticleTitle];
       (articleWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost entryForm;
       defaultLayout $ do { $(widgetFile "articles") } }
In an equation for `postBlogR':
    postBlogR
      = do { articles <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc ArticleTitle];
             (articleWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost entryForm;
             defaultLayout $ do { ... } }
```

this is my Blog.hs:

```
    module Handler.Blog
    ( getBlogR
    , postBlogR
    )
where

import Import

-- to use Html into forms
import Yesod.Form.Nic (YesodNic, nicHtmlField)
instance YesodNic App

entryForm :: Form Article
entryForm = renderDivs $ Article
    <$> areq   textField "Title" Nothing
    <*> areq   nicHtmlField "Content" Nothing

-- The view showing the list of articles
getBlogR :: Handler Html
getBlogR = do
    -- Get the list of articles inside the database.
    articles <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc ArticleTitle]
    -- We'll need the two "objects": articleWidget and enctype
    -- to construct the form (see templates/articles.hamlet).
    (articleWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost entryForm
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "articles")

postBlogR :: handler RepHtml
postBlogR = do
    -- Get the list of articles inside the database.
    articles <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc ArticleTitle]
    -- We'll need the two "objects": articleWidget and enctype
    -- to construct the form (see templates/articles.hamlet).
    (articleWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost entryForm
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "articles")
```

my routes:

```
    /static StaticR Static getStatic
/auth   AuthR   Auth   getAuth

/favicon.ico FaviconR GET
/robots.txt RobotsR GET

/ HomeR GET POST
/echo/#Text EchoR GET
/mirror MirrorR GET POST
/blog BlogR GET POST
/blog/#ArticleId ArticleR GET
```

and  my models:

```
    User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
Email
    email Text
    user UserId Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe
    UniqueEmail email

Article
    title   Text
    content Html
    deriving

 -- By default this file is used in Model.hs (which is imported by Foundation.hs)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, you just have to fix your type signature for `postBlogR` to `Handler RepHtml`. Names starting with lower case letters are reserved for type variables in type signatures, so it cannot be deduced right here.

Comment: That's definitely the problem.  `handler` implies a universally quantified type variable. `Handler` implies a specific concrete type. The error message explains that it inferred `Handler` from the body, which is too specific to be universally quantified.

Comment: What all above said. Also, it says in the tutorial that it's updated to work with Yesod 1.2, and you are clearly using an older version since `GHandler` is being used in your errors. That's a pre-1.2 type. My advice is to update your installation before proceeding, or my guess is you will run into a lot more difficulties.

Comment: Maybe you should additionally change the type to `Handler Html` like it is said in the tutorial?
I'm also wondering, why you have the same code for post and get, but maybe you're just playing around to get it working.